# repeat vba for entireworkbook

Tags: html, excel, vba, ms-office

i have this code for convert xlsm to html . i need repeat this code for entireworkbook and

1-export filename , same as sheet name and in file path

2-select printarea range for convert each sheet

3-every sheet,seperate convert to html

```
Sub Export()
 Dim rng As Range

 file1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.html"

 Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:C10")

 ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
 Filename:=file1, _
 Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
 Source:=rng.Address, _
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub ExportAllSheets()
 Dim rng As Range, file1 As String, sh As Worksheet

 For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   If sh.PageSetup.PrintArea <> "" Then
     Set rng = sh.Range(sh.PageSetup.PrintArea)
     file1 = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & sh.Name & ".html"
     ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
            SourceType:=xlSourceRange, fileName:=file1, _
            sheet:=sh.Name, Source:=rng.Address, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

It should export html files for each sheet, with sheet name as file name.

Comment: this range a1:c10 is not for me and i copied that code , from other site and now i want customize it on printarea

Comment: @Hematin Site: Is the `PrintArea` set, or it must be set according to some criteria?

Comment: @Hematin Site: I adapted the code to process only the sheets having `PrintArea` set and use it like the range to be published.